Boss pushes alcohol on employee then implies he's an alcoholic
I remember a recent comedy where an employee is called into the boss's office and offered a drink.  He refuses, but the boss acts as if he takes offense to the employee not drinking with him.  When the employee finally accepts, the boss pours the employee a drink, but does not drink himself.
The situation clearly makes the employee feel uncomfortable, but he drinks anyway.  The moment he drinks, the boss begins asking him questions such as whether he thinks it's appropriate to drink at the office and whether he usually drinks in the morning.

Horrible Bosses
It's one of the setup scenes with Jason Bateman and Kevin Spacey where Spacey is blackmailing Bateman with the prospect of a promotion.
Relevant Scene:




Thank you!  Good job finding it based on such a poor description.

This also happens in an earlier episode of House of Cards; but that's not a comedy.

@Zaz, I've seen the movie a bunch of times. Much better than the second one.

@JMac does it? I don't recall that but I'm guessing something to do with Russo?

@Steve Yeah, I'm pretty sure it has to do with Russo, very early Season 1 I think.  Remembering back, I think it's a bit more forced and Russo seems to have some idea he's being set up.  Funny enough, I think that's why that scene seemed so familiar to me in House of Cards.  I had already seen Horrible Bosses, but it just occurred to me that it was Kevin Spacey both times.
